# Compare list of times in String (7:08 AM, 10:03 AM) with current local-time in Android / Java

Tags: java, android

I have a list of times in a text file which I am reading line by line.
example, my text file has

```
7:23 AM  
7:38 AM  
7:53 AM  
8:08 AM  
8:23 AM  
8:38 AM  
8:53 AM  
9:08 AM  
9:23 AM  
9:38 AM
```

and so on.

i am able to fetch the time but now i need to compare every item with the localtime (System time in android) and suggest the next time.

So if my local time in system is 8:00 AM, i need to show next available time 8:08 AM

My text file also has times in PM format (after 12:00 PM).

Please suggest the best way to compare.

Comment: Are the times in the file always ordered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to convert the time you are fetching from the text file.
Let take an exmaple of 7:38 AM. 
Split it into 3 parts -

```
 Hour = 7

 Minute = 38

 AM_PM value = AM
```

Now create a Calendar instance with your values -

```
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM); // Calendar.PM for PM
                long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

And Cjurrent time -

```
long currentTimeInMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

Now you can compare `time` and `currentTimeInMillis` the way you want and add your logic to achieve your task.

Comment: You could just use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse out a `Date` object. You don't need to split anything.

Comment: @cricket_007 But there is no Date object in this case. That is a text file storing time in string format only.

Comment: I understand that, but having some `SimpleDateFormat` to `parse("7:38 AM")` will return a `Date`, which can be used in `Calendar.setTime()`... I'm saying you don't need to individually set the values of a `Calendar` if you just parse the String.

Comment: Don't you think in that case, you'll have the date as Jan 01 1970 and not the current date ?

Comment: I guess calling `setTime` would reset the day/month/year... Well, still. I think the answer could be improved by adding the bit about `SimpleDateFormat` instead of "splitting" the times.

Comment: May be. But I'm sure `setTime`  does not changes the date to current date. The date will still be the same.

Comment: i tried separating every thing. i have hour, min and AM_PM value as well. i couldnt figure out the corner cases and the time is in 12 hr format.

Comment: The solution is for 12 hour format only. what is the issue now ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a TreeSet. Creating a TreeSet with the default constructor will return a set that orders elements naturally. Date is an implementer of Comparable, so no extra work is needed there.

Then you can call TreeSet's higher method with your current time to get the first key strictly greater than your time.

So, altogether:

```
TreeSet<Date> dates = new TreeSet<Date>();
//add all dates..

Date next = dates.higher(new Date())
```

**EDIT** I realized you might also be asking how to offset the time, since without year/month/day the parsed date will start from 0 milliseconds.

To get the current time with today's date you could do something like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");

Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (int)format.parse(dateFromFile).getTime());

date.getTime()
```

There might be a better approach, but using SimpleDateFormat is usually a good first step for parsing dates.

**SECOND EDIT** I think there might be some confusion with what I'm suggesting so here is a full solution with different offerings.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(myTimeZone));

date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


TreeSet<Long> timesFromFile = new TreeSet<>();
TreeSet<Date> datesFromFile = new TreeSet<>();

String line;
//i'm using class BufferedReader since it reads lines at a time    
while ((line = bufferedFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (int)format.parse(line).getTime());

    Date dateFromFile = date.getTime();
    long millsecondRepresentation = dateFromFile.getTime();

    datesFromFile.add(dateFromFile);
    timesFromFile.add(millsecondRepresentation);
}


Date now = new Date();
Long higherLong = timesFromFile.higher(now.getTime());
Date higherDate = datesFromFile.higher(now);

assertEquals(new Date(higherLong), higherDate);

assertTrue(now.before(higherDate));
assertTrue(now.getTime() < higherLong);
```

This effectively creates those times with today's date, so that they can be compared with the current time, which will factor today's date into it's timestamp. I do not know of any standard Java method doing time comparison without factoring in the date in some way.

[TreeSet documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#higher(E))

[SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: but how do i compare 2 time instances. i need to compare hours and min and suggest the next greater one. i dont need the date

Comment: The TreeSet is what does the comparison for you (with the method higher). In this case I suggested Date objects because the TreeSet already knows how to order them (because they implement Comparable). The second part of my question covers time comparison. I would still suggest using a Date object if you want to use standard Java. Creating a date with a Calendar like above will allow you to compare time's with today's date. If you are using longs instead for milliseconds, you can still use the same TreeSet technique, and use Date.getTime().getTime() to get milliseconds as a long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.Date.compareTo method:

Example:

```
     Date date = new Date(98, 5, 21);
     Date date2 = new Date(99, 1, 9);

     // make 3 comparisons with them
     int comparison = date.compareTo(date2);
```

This progress will return three value -1 0 1 for greater it will return 1 for equal 0 and -1 for other option.So you can use this method for your program.

I hope ı could help.

Comment: but how does date relate to time. i am looking for comparing time hours and minutes and AM/PM. not the calendar date